# java jdbc mysql cannot connect using password

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I get this error when trying to connect to Db

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'addressapp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at ch.makery.address.mysql.MysqlConnection.test(MysqlConnection.java:29)
at ch.makery.address.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



 static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test";

 //  Database credentials
 static final String USER = "addressapp";
 static final String PASS = "addressapp";

 public void test() {
 Connection conn = null;
 Statement stmt = null;
 try{
    //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //STEP 3: Open a connection
    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
}
    //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
 }catch(SQLException se){
    //Handle errors for JDBC
    se.printStackTrace();
 }catch(Exception e){
    //Handle errors for Class.forName
    e.printStackTrace();
 }finally{
    //finally block used to close resources
    try{
       if(stmt!=null)
          stmt.close();
    }catch(SQLException se2){
    }// nothing we can do
    try{
       if(conn!=null)
          conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
       se.printStackTrace();
    }//end finally try
 }//end try
```

The problem is that

1. I can connect to db using MYSQL workbench using this users credentials
2. I can connect to db using JDBC if there is no password (for example user root, or changing user's addressapp password to blank
3. **I cannot** connect to db when using any password using JDBC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was I had "anonymous" user in my db witch had no password. After removing it the problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Properties  connProps = new Properties ();
connProps.put ("user", USER);
connProps.put ("password", PASS);

Connection  theConnection = DriverManager.getConnection (DB_URL, connProps);
```